# Efficient ways of recognizing lines in a 20x20 pixel square

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, pixel

Efficient ways of recognizing lines and edges in a 20x20 pixel square. I am iterating through an image in 20x20 pixel blocks and want to recognize where there are distinct differences in luminance and highlight all of these edges. There can be multiple lines in the same square overlapping each other.

I am forming an array of the 20x20 pixel block where pixel luminance is l = (0-255) and pixel location is [x, y]
**array = [[l, [x, y]], ...]**

I have attempted so far:

- Finding range to highlight blocks of large differences, however this does not help with picking up the more subtle changes noted in the picture.
- 3xstandard deviation away from average

The way I am iterating through the image is starting at the middle top 20x20 square then working out downwards, left and right (demonstrated by orange). Further following the same pattern (light blue)

It is going to require more complex analysis to pick up the subtle changes in pixel colour. Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

[image: Image for analysis]

Answer (score 1):

This is more or less what a convolutional neuronal network does to recognize different features, you can read about it.

You need to make a kernel (that is a matrix). The kernel will encode the shape you are looking for, with positive numbers normally between 0 and 1.

Then you make a convolution of your kernel over the image, and it will output another image (matrix) highlight the places that are more similar to your kernel, i.e. your corners and lines.

A simple implementation could be found at [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html)

```
scipy.signal.convolve2d
```